# Thread Error while pushing view controller found nil

Tags: swift

I am trying to send the user to another view controller when selecting a cell. I am using the didSelectRowAt function to push the view controller and fill the image and label with data. I am getting a crash that says: **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** in the `pushViewController` line. I am not sure why this error is happening because this worked awhile using another view controller.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    
    let songName = songs[indexPath.row].cleanName
    let fileURLString = "\(filePath)\(songName)"
    print(fileURLString)
    Player.shared.playStream(fileUrl: fileURLString)
    let SvC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SongsPlayerViewController") as? SongPlayerViewController
    
    SvC?.songNames.text = songs[indexPath.row].cleanName
    SvC?.songCover.image = UIImage(named: songs[indexPath.row].cover)
    
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SvC!, animated: true) // Thread 1 CRASH
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is telling you that `SvC` is nil, which means that this line failed:

```
let SvC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SongsPlayerViewController") as? SongPlayerViewController
```

I suspect you haven't assigned the Storyboard identifier, or have misspelled it.

When you use `!`, as in `SvC!`, you are telling the system that if a value is nil, you would like the program to crash. That's actually fairly useful in this kind of code, because you may find it nicer to crash and show you where the problem is, rather than quietly do nothing. However, you are applying the `!` at an unhelpful place. If you want this code to crash on error, you should do that at the assignment of `SvC`, using `as!` rather than `as?`. This would get rid of all of the `?.` in your subsequent calls, and would make the error location much clearer.